# How to pass a dictionary in params for requests.api.request?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, get, python-requests

I need to pass a dictionary for my get requests, but when executed like this I get a compilation error :

```
patVect = {"poo": 0, "pin": 0, "pok": 0, "pat": 0}
# querystring = {"patients": "{\"poo\":0, \"pin\":0, \"pok\":0, \"pat\":0}"}
querystring = {"patients": patVect}
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
}
response = requests.api.request('get', HURL, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
```

when I am working with the commented query that works fine. any idea why that doesn't work, or a function that will help.

Comment: That's weird, can you debug print querystring before calling api.request and show what its value?

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: You are right, thanks for the sting, the problem is in the server, my error is connection still open. 
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

Comment: Finally I have another problem, that pass but in stead of getting my original dict {"poo": 0, "pin": 0, "pok": 0, "pat": 0}
I just get {"poo", "pin", "pok", "pat"}

Comment: Why don't you `json.dumps(patVect)`?

Comment: thanks adams, I didn't know that params needed to be encoded, that works fine with that

Answer (score 1):

the problem is : 
querystring = {"patients": json.dumps(patVect)}

Answer (score 1):

You can test that API using Postman, you can pass the `dict` parameter as raw `JSON` in the body section.

Then when you have tested the API call you can go ahead and generate the code for it in your preferred language.

This is as `Python Requests`:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8000/foo/bar/"

payload = "{\n\t\"dict\": {\n\t\t\"key1\": \"value1\",\n\t\t\"key2\": \"value2\"\n\t}\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': <TOKEN>
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

This is as `Python http.client(Python3)`:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost")

payload = "{\n\t\"dict\": {\n\t\t\"key1\": \"value1\",\n\t\t\"key2\": \"value2\"\n\t}\n}"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': <TOKEN>
    }

conn.request("GET", "foo,bar,", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```